# .NET project in a solution should generate an exe but only makes a setup file and shortcut

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, scheduled-tasks

I've inherited an old .NET MVC C# website. Bundled into the solution is a 'SearchUpdater' program which seems to be some kind of service:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase {
```

It seems to be an application, on properties we see:

```
Output type: Windows Application
Target framework: .NET Framework 4
```

This somehow translates to a SearchUpdater.exe file we have on the web server which is run every day. The code deletes a search index text file and then rebuilds it.

Simple, except I need to update the code logic and replace the .exe.

When I do this I can't seem to generate the .exe file any way I try. If I 'publish' the SearchUpdater project I get a local 'setup.exe' file, which, when I run it generates a kind of SearchUpdater 'shortcut' in my start menu which is a

```
Type of file: Application Reference (.appref-ms)
Location: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\HP Inc
```

There's no 'target'...

Basically, I can't find a .exe file anywhere to replace the one on our webserver!

Any ideas? I'm a bit lost with this one, how can I generate a .exe, and will I need to do this somehow on the webserver? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just do a Release build and check `bin\Release`?

Comment: When I do a release build there is no bin\Release!

Comment: Then check the project's output directory on the Build tab on its properties.

Comment: Do not use "publish".  Simply copy the .exe file from the project's bin\Release directory and use installutil.exe to install it.  Although that shouldn't be necessary when you simply need to update the existing .exe file.

Comment: There is no .exe file to copy... In Build properties for the SearchUpdater shows bin\Release. When you say just do a build and not publish, if I do a build where can I find the files that are created?

Comment: I found it! It's listed on the build output :) 
C:\Users\Me\Documents\CODE\company\git-project\SearchUpdater\bin\Release

Comment: I think this was a case of simply not understanding what is produced on a build vs a publish in this case. I had no idea the .exe was only produced on builds. :) Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to suggestions by [@codecaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster) and [@hans-passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant). If you **build** the project in **release** mode, then go to the solution folder and check in the correct bin folder there is indeed a 'release' folder that will contain the .exe file (or did for me!).